# How do I change the resolution on my windows 8 laptop?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, resolution, windows-8-preview, toshiba-laptop

I had the Windows 8 consumer preview from when it came out until the new Windows 8 Release preview came out a few days ago.

I recently updated my computer and I noticed that my resolution went back to 1024 x 768 with no way for me to change it.  I have had this happen to me before, but I solved it by going back to Windows 7 temporarily, installing the driver for my graphics card and reinstalling Windows 8.

I don't want to do all that again, mostly because I ran out of computers I can download Microsoft Office on, but I also don't want to have to reinstall everything AGAIN!  How can I change my resolution to be higher than the default without having to downgrade?

Here is my computer information:

- Operating System: Windows 8 Release Preview 32-bit
- Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
- System Model: Satellite A215
- Graphics Card: ATI Radeon X1200 Series

Comment: Why not download the Windows 7 drivers for your card, from inside Windows 8? I'm not sure how going back to Windows 7 temporarily worked, exactly.

Comment: I'll try that...